# python pandas - function applied to csv is not persisted

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to polish a csv dataset, but it seems the changes are not applied to the dataset itslef.

CSV is in this format:

```
ID,     TRACK_LINK
761607, https://mylink.com//track/...
```

This is my script:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./file.csv').fillna('')

# remove double // from TRACK_LINK
def polish_track_link(track_link):
    return track_link.replace("//track", "/track")

df['LINK'].apply(polish_track_link)

print(df)
```

this prints something like:

```
...
761607    https://mylink.com//track/...
```

note the `//track`

If I do `print(df['LINK'].apply(polish_track_link))` I get:

```
...
761607, https://mylink.com/track/...
```

So the function `polish_track_link` works but it's not applied to the dataset. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need assign back:

```
df['TRACK_LINK'] = df['TRACK_LINK'].apply(polish_track_link)
```

But better is use pandas functions [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) or [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `regex=True` for replace substrings:

```
df['TRACK_LINK'] = df['TRACK_LINK'].str.replace("//track", "/track")
```

Or:

```
df['TRACK_LINK'] = df['TRACK_LINK'].replace("//track", "/track", regex=True)
```

---

```
print(df)
       ID                 TRACK_LINK
0  761607  https://mylink.com/track/
```